# Build error: Cached player destination differs from selected player destination

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had a problem with my unity project build, I add SDK last version in Unity preference but the bellow error was generated.

---

```
Error building scripts: Cached player destination differs from selected player destination. Please disable scripts only build and build again before attempting another scripts only build.

Build completed with a result of 'Failed UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building scripts: Cached player destination differs from selected player destination. Please disable scripts only build and build again before attempting another scripts only build

  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:182
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Did you do what the error message says to do?

Comment: I didn't understand what it means !!! can you explain that to me?

Comment: In the build settings window there is a check box for "Scripts Only Build". Uncheck that box.

Comment: OK great, thank you  a lot Ninja for your support.